# How do i get string list of username and fullname from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In java class, I used some random username and fullname for testing but now I want to get the list of username and full name of user who are child of current user in Mates node in firebase.

```
public class User
{

    public String fullname;
    public String username;




      public User()
        {
            FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Mates").child(uid);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<User> USERS = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                        USERS.add(user);
                        Log.d(TAG, user.getUsername() + " / " + user.getFullname());
                    }

                    //Do what you need to do with your userList
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }

        public User(String fullname, String username) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.username = username;
        }


        public String getFullname() {
            return fullname;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public static List<User> USERS ;

    }
```

I want replace this user to firebase user who is child of current user, here I put my database image.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what is the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: Take datasnapshot from Users child who are placed in Mates node under current uid

Comment: So to understand better, you want to use the uid `21va ... qTH2` to get the object within `Mates -> 21va ... qTH2`, right? Those are also user objects, right? With only two properties, is this correct?

Comment: Yes and 21va...qTH2 is current uid

Comment: This is absolutely correct what you say

Comment: Please see my answer below and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, to get all user objects that exist within `Mates/uid`, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Mates").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
            userList.add(user);
            Log.d(TAG, user.getUsername() + " / " + user.getFullname());
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your userList
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be all usernames and fullnames of all users that exist within the uid.

Comment: class files edited app is crashed, please what i had mistake ?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please add the changed code.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: At which exact line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: Its comes from my other activities which is using this class file

Comment: That issue is apart of another class and is not related with this question.

Comment: Yes, you edited code is right. Try to comment the code that is using that class file and tell me if it works, ok?

Comment: Yes but i tried to just replace username and fullname with firebase. Ok i got the list from firebase but how i implements in method. public User(String fullname, String username) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.username = username;

Comment: Good to hear that you got the list :) I'm affraid I don't understand what you are asking. So it's better to post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I am using autocomplete from this library. https://github.com/natario1/Autocomplete

Comment: This is what I was talking about. Post another question regarding this new problem. In a post, we stick to one question at a time.

Comment: ok Got it and thanx for helping and please go through my other question as you say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815932/how-do-i-replace-data-with-firebase-in-below-mentioned-autocomplte-library

Answer (score 0):

make it clear you want to replace full name , username from java class to firebase. 
right ?

Comment: Yes brother. Take snapshot from User child who are child of current uid in Mates node. And replace username and fullname by firebase datasanpshot

Answer (score 0):

Your class User attributes might be `private` else you will get an error of fetching data from Firebase. 
Visit this link for working with list https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=0