# How do I replace data with firebase in below mentioned Autocomplete library?

Tags: java, android

For the Editext autocomplete I got the library from internet.
In `User.java` class, they used some random username and fullname for testing but now I want to get the list of username and full name of user who are child of current user in Mates node in firebase.
Thanx to natario1/Autocomplete

```
public class User {

private String fullname;
private String username;
private boolean female;

public User(String fullname, String username) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.username = username;
}

public User(String fullname, String username, boolean female) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.username = username;
    this.female = female;
}

public String getFullname() {
    return fullname;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public boolean isFemale() {
    return female;
}

// Thanks uinames.com
public static List<User> USERS = Arrays.asList(
        new User("Lori Rice", "lori__rice", true),
        new User("Karen Sandoval", "karen93", true),
        new User("Andrea Wagner", "andrea_86"),
        new User("Jerry Sanchez", "jerry-85"),
        new User("Elizabeth Carroll", "elizabeth-94", true),
        new User("Ronald Tran", "ronald_tran"),
        new User("Crystal Castillo", "crystal.castillo", true),
        new User("Sean King", "sean"),
        new User("Paul Aguilar", "paul.aguilar"),
        new User("Benjamin Gonzalez", "ben-85"),
        new User("Ryan Curtis", "ryan-94"),
        new User("Jane Willis", "jane_willis", true),
        new User("Diane Price", "diane__price", true),
        new User("Marie Elliott", "marie95", true),
        new User("Peter Cole", "peter_83"),
        new User("Donald Green", "donald-35"),
        new User("Frank Oliver", "frank-oliver"),
        new User("Doris Walters", "doris", true),
        new User("Jack Lynch", "jack-lynch"),
        new User("Ruth Patel", "patel"),
        new User("Donald Obrien", "obrien.donald"),
        new User("Joyce Wells", "jwells"),
        new User("Austin Keller", "keller-94"),
        new User("Jean Watkins", "jw", true),
        new User("Julio Cesar Paredes", "julio.cesar"),
        new User("Fabian Mercedesz", "fabian"),
        new User("Roma Kania", "roma.kania", true),
        new User("Luna Vidal", "luna-75", true),
        new User("Daisy Roberts", "roberts-93", true),
        new User("Matthew Maxton", "matthew_maxton"),
        new User("Claudio Guerra", "guerra.claudio"),
        new User("Floare Carafoli", "floare84", true),
        new User("Esra Yilmaz", "esra_83", true),
        new User("Casanda Goian", "casanda-1935", true),
        new User("Kyle Lawson", "kyle-law"),
        new User("Mathijs de Boer", "mdboer"),
        new User("Mitchell Sarah", "mitchell-sarah"),
        new User("Carolina Rotaru", "rotaru", true),
        new User("Joe Fernandez", "joe.fernandez"),
        new User("Christian Colombo", "ccolombo"),
        new User("Venera Steflea", "venera-91", true),
        new User("Helge Olsen", "holsen", true),
        new User("Fien Smet", "fien.smet"),
        new User("Hugo Aviles", "aviles"),
        new User("Elizabeth Montoya", "elizabeth.montoya", true),
        new User("Mihnea Gliga", "mihnea-75", true),
        new User("Gary Cook", "cook-96"),
        new User("Seppe Smet", "seppe_smet"),
        new User("Diane Lane", "diane.lane", true),
        new User("Sophia Ackroyd", "sophia", true),
        new User("Octavia Sirma", "octavia_sirma", true),
        new User("Ciprian Tutoveanu", "ciprian"),
        new User("Ida Birkeland", "birkeland-ida", true),
        new User("Tore Haugland", "torehaug"),
        new User("Denis Vaska", "denis-vaska"),
        new User("Milena Corbea", "corbeamilena", true),
        new User("Gyurkovics Letti", "gyur.letti "),
        new User("Oliviu Fugaru", "oliviufu"),
        new User("Semiha Erdem", "semi-91"),
        new User("Codin Ardelean", "codin.ardelean")
);
}
```

I want replace this user to firebase user who is child of current user, here I put my database image.

Comment: If you want to use those user objects, add them to the database first and then get all users back in a list as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55814211/5246885).

Comment: I already did this in my previous question edited

Comment: Then why to use that list from your model class, if it is already in your database?

Comment: Hey brother please dont laugh on my self ,i am not computer or software engineer but im Being Mechanical Engineer so i m in trouble with this types of  questions thanx again

Comment: I just asked you a question, to understand your problem better. No one laughs. So why to use that list from your model class, if it is already in your database?

Comment: because in this library they use model class for this , and i did same

Comment: There is no need to use that list since all those users are already in the database and you know how to get them.

Comment: In fact every time i trouble when get the list from firebase without model class

Comment: You can also get the data from the database without using a model class.

Comment: and but how to cast as list?

Comment: Call getData() and iterate throught the Map that is returned.